# Can't use insert Google Analytics API - 403 - Your Project Doesn't Have Access to This Feature

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I've seen posts from 2014 addressing this issue, stating that it's because write operations are still in beta, but is this still the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes

[Details](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/account-management): Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete, patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources is currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're interested in using these features, [request access to the beta](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1xyjp6ca4YkGjh7TDi1Z3XyA3XHcRHkKzFentxzUrmPY/viewform).